# Sign up for Google Analytics without SMS verifcation

Tags: google-analytics

Is there any way to sign up for a Google Analytics account without having to verify the account via an SMS code?

You used to be able to verify via an email code, but this no longer appears to be an option.

Comment: I just signed up without any SMS code. Are you trying to sign-up on gmail or GA?

Comment: @Prasad is right, when you create accounts on Google it can get confusing where you are actually registering. Gmail requires phone verification. A regular Google Account does not which you can then use to setup Analytics. Try going here to signup for a Google Account https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can still do this by creating a google account, then once you have that sign up for an analytics account.